# Let User Re-type The Input Without Interfering With Other Strings (C#)

Tags: c#, output, user-input, presentation, tryparse

My input gets checked by "TryParse". And if it is false I want to let the user retype it correctly. But when I click any key after the check it deletes everything above cause of "Console.Clear();". - I want to delete only the input part and nothing above it.

```
namespace Practice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)     // Main Method
        {
            byte age1, age2;
            string input;

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Age 1: "); input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!byte.TryParse(input, out age1)) Error();
            } while (!byte.TryParse(input, out age1));

            do
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Age 2: "); input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!byte.TryParse(input, out age1)) Error();
            } while (!byte.TryParse(input, out age2));
        }

        static void Error()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Write("Invalid Input...");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about your code style?

Comment: `byte age1, age2` should that be `int || Int32` also please fix the poorly formatted code.. also do not put multiple lines of code that do separate things on a single line.. makes it hard to read what you are trying to do and can easily be looked over or missed also on this line `Console.WriteLine("Age 1-> {0}` it would be cleaning in my opinion if you would use `string.Format()` method

Comment: There's no reason for byte to be changed...byte its 0-255 and I don't think many people live to be close to that age.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can erase a single line from the Console buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can erase a single line from the Console buffer. But you can simulate it if you change the second while in your code:

`while (!byte.TryParse(input, out age2) && counter)
            {
                Error();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Age 1: {0}",age1);
                Console.Write("Enter Age 2: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            } // Check And Error Output`

with this line `Console.WriteLine("Enter Age 1: {0}",age1);` after the `Console.Clear();` executes, It seems like you have erased the wrong input line.

Comment: I appreciate it man, I'm thanking you for your response. You helped me. - I apologise if you couldn't understand my question or couldn't read my code. Kinda silly complains from experienced programmers but whatever. - I'm learning C# in the institute for 1 year so far. And I thought it would be handy to learn such presentation feature where invalid input gets removed and replaced by a new string, without clearing everything above. -> If you're curious you can see what I've done-> http://pastebin.com/4v58razK

Comment: @monstrasitix: Glad I helped you. If you can please accept my answer. I saw your code in pastebin. If your age variables keeps growing you should encapsulate the age checking and printing in a method. making your code easier to read and follow when errors appear.